# Предотвращение конфликтов при создании и удалении таблицы в SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Есть приложение на C# которое создает таблицу бд, заполняет ее необходимыми значениями, выгружает результат в xml, а затем удаляет таблицу созданную на первом шаге. Все работает через `SqlCommand`, запросы берутся из файла. Так как выгружается большой объем данных, то возможна ситуация когда будут запущены два экземпляра программы и например одна программа сработает быстрее и удалит таблицу. Как можно избежать данных вариантов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server не умеет выполнять запросы DDL полностью в транзакциях. Так умеет Postgres, например.

Так или иначе, **так делать не надо**. Таблица в базе данных — это постоянное хранилище, а не временное. Если вы постоянно создаёте и уничтожаете постоянное хранилище, с архитектурой приложения что-то нет так.

Удаление таблицы до того, как один процесс закончил выгрузку данных — это меньшая из ваших проблем. Что будет, если второму процессу достанется смесь данных, загруженных им и соседним процессом? На выходе будет мусор.

1. Вы можете добавить в вашу таблицу поле `SessionId`, чтобы каждый экземпляр приложения работал со своей частью таблицы.
2. Вы можете разграничивать доступ к базе данных на уровне операционной системы, чтобы базу одновременно не изменяло два процесса.
3. Если всё, что вам надо — это обработать данные с помощью SQL, то в зависимости от объёмов можете или размещать данные в памяти и вообще не прикасаться к SQL, или воспользоваться файловыми базами данных типа SQL Compact, или использовать что-то ещё гораздо легковеснее, чем SQL Server.

Comment: А как разграничить доступ к базе на уровне ОС?

Answer (score 5):

Зачем создавать таблицу только чтобы потом удалить ее?

Судя по описанию, после работы программы можно удалять не просто таблицу - а всю БД. В таком случае подойдет монопольный режим работы с БД.

Еще вариант - при запуске генерировать уникальное имя таблицы. Разные экземпляры программы будут работать с разными таблицами.

Ну и банальных транзакций никто не отменял, хоть их и не рекомендуют использовать для больших объемов данных.

**UPD:**
А, так вам нужны дополнительные таблицы в сложных выборках? Посмотрите справочник по T-SQL (Transact-SQL), особенно оператор [`DECLARE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188927.aspx). Этот оператор позволяет создать, в том числе, временную таблицу, которая будет видна *только* в рамках некоторого пакета запросов.

Ничего не помешает выполнять два пакета запросов одновременно - у каждого пакета будет своя таблица. Такую таблицу даже не нужно удалять - она удалится автоматически по окончанию пакета.

Comment: Генерировать уникальное имя таблицы - рассматривал такой вариант, но он не подходит так как запросы берутся из xml файла, это требование. А что за "банальные транзакции"?

Comment: Как зачем? Например из нескольких десятков таблиц выбирается  необходимая информация, которую надо выгрузить в xml.

Answer (score 2):

Блокировка на уровне БД, использование мьютекса для синхронизации работы экземпляров. Использование мьютекса для запрета запуска второго приложения. Выбирайте что вам больше подходит.

Comment: А можно на примерах, не совсем понятно, спасибо

Comment: LOCK TABLES в mysql, например.

Comment: В вопросе ms sql, такой инструкции там нет

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю создавать временную таблицу в процедуре.

Comment: Временную таблицу через # ? Так не получится, я сначала ее создаю, потом с помощью `bcp` разбираю на xml.

Comment: @e1s, можно и через @, не только через #. Почему так не получится?

Comment: Я ее создал - `create table`, затем заполняю, следующая команда `SqlCommand`, она уже не будет доступна. А мне ее еще надо разобрать на xml  с помощью `bcp`

Comment: Почему вместо `create table` не сделать в самой SqlCommand `declare @smth as table(тут то же самое, что в create)`?

Comment: Допустим я делаю так в C# - `comm.ComandText = "declare @smth...."` затем `comm.ExecuteNonQuery()`, когда я меняю допустим `CommandText` на Insert будет ли существовать таблица? И исключает ли это ситуацию когда например в сети будут запущенны два экземпляра приложения примерно в одно время?